# Postgres calling rollback in a procedure that's called from another procedure fails

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, transactions

I have a problem where I have a procedure called `outer` that loops on a table to get IDs and then calls an `inner` procedure passing in the ID but fails. The problem is that sometimes something bad happens on the `inner` procedure and I want to rollback and log what it was that caused the error, and then have the `outer` procedure continue looping on other jobs.

I execute this in DataGrip like so: `call source_pending_jobs();`

I get an error `invalid transaction termination 2D000` that I'm sure is the fault of the ROLLBACK on the `inner` procedure and I can't save off any of the error info.

I'm sure that this is a misunderstanding of mine w.r.t. transactions in Postgres. Does this pattern work, or am I doing something wrong?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE outer()
  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
  AS
$$
DECLARE
  v_job_id integer;
BEGIN
  FOR v_job_id IN SELECT job_id FROM pending_jobs ORDER BY job_id
  LOOP
    BEGIN
      CALL inner(v_job_id);
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RAISE NOTICE 'Job Id: %', v_job_id;
      RAISE NOTICE '% %', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE;
      RETURN;
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE inner(last_job_id integer)
AS $$
DECLARE
  v_pending_updates_rowcount integer;
  v_existing_updates_rowcount integer;
BEGIN
    -- Bad thing happens where which causes execution to enter following conditional. 
    IF v_pending_updates_rowcount <> v_existing_updates_rowcount THEN
      ROLLBACK;

      INSERT INTO blocked_jobs (job_id) VALUES (last_job_id);
      DELETE FROM pending_jobs WHERE job_id = last_job_id;

      COMMIT;
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Update failed!';
    END IF;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: The transaction cannot be terminated in _inner_ because a `SELECT` is performed in _outer_ prior to calling _inner_. Try using `SAVEPOINT ...` and `ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT ...` to recover to a known good transaction state. You could also try terminating the transaction in _outer_ prior to calling _inner_. A combination of the two may be required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `EXCEPTION` handler in `outer`. You cannot `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` while you are in a block with an exception handler: that would make it impossible to undo the effects of the block in the case of an exception.

Remove that exception handler, and the code should work.